# Variable is not updating at the end of the function chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function newBusRoute() {
    busRoute += 1;
    routeName = "Bus Route " + busRoute;
    routeArrayBusRoutes.push(routeName);
    vehArrayBusRoutes.push(0);
    updateRoutes(routeArrayBusRoutes, vehArrayBusRoutes, "busRoutesListDiv", 600, "maintBus", maintBus, 99, 50, "vehCountBus");
}

function updateRoutes(routeArray, vehArray, listid, cost, maintType, maintCost, eivPlus, capacityPlus, vehCountType) {
    document.getElementById(listid).innerHTML = "";
    for (I in routeArray) {
        document.getElementById(listid).innerHTML += ("<button onclick='editRoute(\""+I+"\", \""+vehArray[I]+"\", \""+vehArray+"\", \""+cost+"\", \""+maintType+"\", \""+maintCost+"\", \""+eivPlus+"\", \""+capacityPlus+"\", \""+vehCountType+"\")'>"+routeArray[I]+"</button>");
    }
}

function editRoute(route, vehCount, vehArray, cost, maintType, maintCost, eivPlus, capacityPlus, vehCountType) {
    $("#mainContainer").fadeOut();
    document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = (
        "<h1>Bus Route "+route+"</h1>" +
        "<p id='routeVehCount'>Vehicles on this route: "+vehCount +
        "<p><button onclick='addVeh(\""+route+"\", \""+vehArray+"\", \""+cost+"\", \""+maintType+"\", \""+maintCost+"\", \""+eivPlus+"\", \""+capacityPlus+"\", \""+vehCountType+"\")'>+ Add Vehicle | Cost: £600 | Maintenance: £50 per day</button>"
    );
    $("#screen").fadeIn();
    $("#closeButton").fadeIn();
}

function addVeh(route, vehArray, cost, maintType, maintCost, eivPlus, capacityPlus, vehCountType) {
    vehArray[route] += 1;
    vehCountType += 1;
    bank -= cost;
    checkBank;
    maintCost = Number(maintCost);
    maintType += maintCost;
    checkIncome();
    eiv = Number(eiv);
    eiv += Number(eivPlus);
    checkEIV();
    capacity = Number(capacity);
    capacity += capacityPlus;
    checkCapacity();
}
```

Hi, I've written these functions. I know they look messy but essentially all the variables get passed along the functions from `updateRoutes()` to `addVeh()`. All of them work fine, apart from `"vehCountBus"`, which is passed along as `vehCountType`. No errors are thrown, it just simply doesn't update unless I manually replace `vehCountType` in `addVeh()` to `vehCountBus`.

Why is the value of `vehCountType` not carried through like the other variables?

Comment: It's not clear to me what specifically you're describing.  Can you narrow down the problem to a specific operation in the code?  Where is a value first being observed as incorrect?  When you update the DOM with new markup populated by your values, what is that resulting markup and how is it incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

The simple example of your problem is this:

```js
function increaseA(a) {
    a += 1;
}
let a = 1;
increaseA(a);
console.log(a); // Still 1, not 2
```

The problem is that `a += 1` in `increaseA` updates the **parameter** `a`. It has no effect whatsoever on the `a` **variable** defined outside of `increaseA`. When you do

```
increaseA(a);
```

the **value** of `a` is read, then that *value* (not a link to the `a` variable) is passed into `increaseA`.

If you want to have a function change a variable that isn't defined within the function, your options are:

1. Have it directly reference the variable by *closing over* it.
2. Have it return a new value that you assign to the variable (`a = increaseA(a)`).

You may be wondering why `vehArray[route] += 1;` works, given the above. It works because that's changing the state of an object, not the value of a variable/parameter. If you'd done `vehArray = []` instead, changing the value of the `vehArray` parameter, that too wouldn't have any effect outside the function.

You could use that fact to refactor your code to pass an object with named properties into your function, then change the state of the object (assigning new values to its properties). For instance:

```js
function increaseA(object) {
    object.a += 1;
}
let object = {
    a: 1
};
increaseA(object);
console.log(object.a); // 2
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! Your advice allowed me to figure out the problem. I found that using window[] worked.

Comment: @KiranEvans - That does work (because global variables declared with `var` are automatically made properties of the global object, which you can access via `window`), but it's not best practice. :-)